# ASP.NET project creation and loading failure in Visual Studio 2015 over mapped network drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Firstly the solutions I have found yet in various websites, are for older Visual Studio versions.

### My configuration is:

- *Visual Studio 2015* installed in *Windows 10 virtual machine*
  (*VMware*)
- A shared folder which is treated as a *network drive* and mapped as *Z:\* in the VM

### What I can do successfully:

- Creation, loading and debugging **Visual C# Windows Forms Application** in the network drive in the VM
- The same above for **Visual C# ASP.NET Web Application** but only in a local drive

### What I cannot do successfully:

- Creation, loading and debugging **Visual C# ASP.NET Web Application** in the network drive in the VM

### Error messages I get:

- **During creation:** `Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))` error message
- **During loading:** If a *Visual C# ASP.NET Web Application* project is successfully created in a local drive, moved to the network drive and then opened from the network drive in the VM, I get the error message:

  ```
  Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:2648/ failed with the error:
  Filename: \\?\Z:\Test Projects\WebApplication1\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
  Error: Cannot read configuration file
  ```

  But the configuration file `applicationhost.config` is still there.

How to solve the issue for the above given configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a workaround for the issue. I have both a local folder and a shared folder for the same ASP.NET project. I always open the `SLN` file (project solution file for Visual Studio) from the local folder in the VM. I periodically run a process in the VM to synchronize the changes in the both folders (local and shared) so that both folders can contain exactly same files. I actually use *FreeFileSync* app for it. In this workaround, file merge conflict may occur if same files are edited both in the VM and the host before last synchronization. In this case I can review the changes in the conflicted files to resolve conflict. My answer is really a workaround but it works.

Comment: It sounds like things would be so much better if you just used source control instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permission issue to the file. 
Double check the identity you are using for your site (in IIS) Network Services, Local System or whatever

1. In IIS under `Application Pools` under 'Advanced settings' get
   the pool identity name.
2. Give full access to that identity for your `web.config` file
   (even better for the whole folder application)
3. Do the same for `IIS_IUSRS` group

Comment: I could not understand the steps you have described. However I have made my own solution to the issue. It is actually a workaround.